# How do I create a 'coin' in aframe?

Tags: aframe

I would like to create a 'coin' in a-frame.
In other words: a cylinder primitive with an image texture only on the top face, not on the side and bottom. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Sofar I created a cylinder but image texture is also shown on the sides. I created a circle primitive but this primitive has no 'thickness'.

Comment: Combine a cylinder with a circle with material on the circle only

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/msfyp8La/